# How do I use the f commands on a laptop with pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have tried to use the hotkey command, and the press command multiple times, and the volume will not go up. My laptop has <kbd>F8</kbd> as it's volume up key; but sometimes, you have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>fn</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> key to use it. I tried this, and nothing happens. passed through prints, but nothing else happens. Here is the code. What could I do to press the <kbd>F8</kbd> key?

```
import serial
import time
import pyautogui

arduino_serial = serial.Serial('com3', 9600)
time.sleep(2)

while True:
    incoming = str(arduino_serial.readline())
    print(incoming)

    if 'COMMAND1' in incoming:
        pyautogui.hotkey("ctrl", "f8")
        print('passed through')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your actual problem is "how to press the volume up key [which happens to be Fn+F8 on my physical keyboard]".

For that, the solution is likely

```
pyautogui.press("volumeup")
```

(see [this list](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys) for more special key names.)